# About arbitrary data

Tags: node.js, dropbox, dropbox-api

What is arbitrary data ? I found it here  https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#oa2-authorize

```
 state Up to 200 bytes of arbitrary data that will be passed back to your redirect 
 URI. This parameter should be used to protect against cross-site request forgery 
(CSRF). See Sections 4.4.1.8 and 4.4.2.5 of the OAuth 2.0 threat model spec.
```

So what types of value I send for `state` ? I am using nodejs .

Comment: It's called a [Synchronizer Token Pattern](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). Basically, it's (up to) 200 bytes of randomly generated data that you can use to match the authorization with the redirect, thus ensuring that a 3rd party isn't tricking your user into logging into your app and doing something funky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Arbitrary data" means anything.  A string, a number, binary data, whatever.

Since it's to be used as a CSRF token, it needs to be an unpredictable value that's associated with the user's session.  [Here are some guidelines](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation%3a_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern) on CSRF tokens.